# React filtering array of object by input text and category selection by button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

Example of code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-filtering-hooks-search-category?embed=1&file=index.js

In the above StackBlitz example, I am attempting to filter a list of items from a search input as well as by filtering out by categories through buttons. I already have this working with the search input and one button toggle, but I am struggling to make this conditional to work with multiple category selections. I'm stuck on coming up with the expression that filters by searchText as well as all the combinations of category selections. as seen in the logic below:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const searchRegex = searchText && new RegExp(`${searchText}`, "i");
    const filteredData = items.filter(
      (item) =>

        (!searchRegex ||
          searchRegex.test(item.title) ||
          !searchRegex ||
          searchRegex.test(item.source)) &&

        (!productsFilter || item.type === "product")
    );
    setFilteredItems(filteredData);
  }, [searchText, productsFilter, resourceFilter, extraFilter]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I started by removing the individual state you had for each filter and created a new one, which simply represented Filter as a whole:

```js
const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState(new Set());
```

As each filter is selected, we can check the Set if it's included. If it is, we can remove it, otherwise we can insert it:

```js
  const filterClick = (value) => {
    if (filter.has(value)) {
      setFilter(prevFilter => {
        const newSet = new Set(prevFilter);
        newSet.delete(value);
        return newSet;
      });
    } else {
       setFilter(prevFilter => {
        const newSet = new Set(prevFilter);
        newSet.add(value);
        return newSet;
      });
    }
  };
```

We can indicate the ToggleButton is selected by checking the filter state:

```
    <ToggleButton
      togglable={true}
      selected={filter.has("product")}
      onClick={() => filterClick("product")}
    >
```

Finally I combine this, together with your Input Search so we can filter on both the Filter and the Input Search:

```
  let filteredItems = items.filter(item => {
    if (filter.size > 0 && !filter.has(item.type))
      return false;

    if (searchText.length > 0 && !`${item.title}${item.descriptoin}`.includes(searchText))
      return false;

    return true;
  }).map((item, i) => <li>{item.title} <br/><span>{item.descriptoin}</span></li>);
```

btw: `descriptoin` is spelt incorrectly and should be description.

I have a working example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-filtering-hooks-search-category-fktr2w

Comment: Great solution, thank you! Just to note I added toLowerCase() to the following line to make the search more user friendly:
`.filter(item => searchText.length === 0 || `${item.title.toLowerCase()}`
`${item.source.toLowerCase()}`.includes(searchText.toLowerCase()));`

Comment: That's no problem, glad I could help! I just noticed your regex and that suggestion makes sense!